# Is GROUP BY required with COUNT()?

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query is intended to return the student name, her schools name, and her school districts name plus the number of schools in her district. Does `GROUP BY d.id` do anything?  It appears that the `COUNT()` in the SELECT statement magically does the same thing.  If not necessary, is it good practice?

```
SELECT s.name student_name, sc.name school_name, d.name district_name,
COUNT(sc.id) school_count_at_students_district
FROM students s
INNER JOIN schools sc ON sc.id=s.schools_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN schools sc2 ON sc2.districts_id=sc.districts_id
INNER JOIN districts d ON d.id=sc.districts_id
WHERE s.id=123;
```

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function." If you break this rule older MySQL versions do things differently, in a somewhat unpredictable way. Newer MySQL versions will however raise an error.

Comment: It's really tough answer this with all fake column names and no idea of what you're trying to accomplish with your query.

Comment: @jarlh  Ah, so with my data, it "might" produce the results as long as each record contained the group column?

Comment: @user2278120  I am trying to return the record without the `LEFT JOIN` and also return the number of times `t2` is also linked to `t3`.

Comment: @user1032531, can't tell, I never break that rule!

Comment: This question is non-sensical. Does x+y always equal a-b?

Comment: @user2278120  I changed the query to add context.

Comment: @Strawberry  I changed the query a bit.  Grouping on the district does not appear to change the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have the following table:

```
+----+-----+-----------+
| f1 | f2  |    f3     |
+----+-----+-----------+
|  1 | 4.3 | apple     |
|  2 | 1.4 | orange    |
|  2 | 3   | pear      |
|  3 | 1.2 | kiwi      |
|  3 | 2.2 | pineapple |
|  3 | 1   | pineapple |
+----+-----+-----------+
```

And you execute:

```
SELECT f1, sum(f2), f3 FROM table GROUP BY f1, f3;
```

We include the `f1` and `f3` columns in the GROUP BY to tell mysql how to aggregate. You'll get back:

```
+----+-----+-----------+
| f1 | f2  |    f3     |
+----+-----+-----------+
|  1 | 4.3 | apple     |
|  2 | 1.4 | orange    |
|  2 | 3   | pear      |
|  3 | 1.2 | kiwi      |
|  3 | 3.3 | pineapple |
+----+-----+-----------+
```

Here we get distinct groupings of `f1` and `f3` records, like we expect.

If you omit either `f1` or `f3` in the GROUP BY every RDBMS on the planet is going to throw an error, except MySQL. Non-MySQL DBs require you to be explicit about how you are summarizing your fields and they either must be grouped up in the `GROUP BY` or aggregated with a formula in the `SELECT`.

If, in MySQL, you omit the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT f1, sum(f2), f3 FROM table;
```

you will get records back like:

```
+----+-----+-----------+
| f1 | f2  |    f3     |
+----+-----+-----------+
|  1 | 4.3 | apple     |
|  2 | 4.4 | orange    |    
|  3 | 4.5 | kiwi      |    
+----+-----+-----------+
```

Which might be nonsense. The referential integrity of your records has been compromised. `Oranges` are not `4.4` and `Kiwi` is not `4.5`. What MySQL has done is grabbed the first value it came across in the table and spit it out. This behavior might make sense if:

1. You don't care much about which value MySQL picks from `f3` or...
2. You are relying on the storage engine of MySQL to maintain the order of your records, which consequently, makes you a fool. Don't do that.

Your best bet for code portability and unexpected results is to include a `GROUP BY` if you are aggregating with a function in your `SELECT`. Otherwise you'll get what you deserve.

Comment: Thanks JNevill.  For my specific data, I was getting identical results which confused me.  Yes, I was using MySQL.  I have since added the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: `GROUP BY` is one of those odd things in DBMS's. You would think that omitting the GROUP BY statement when you are aggregating a field in SELECT, that the DBMS would just assume that any non-formula aggregated fields would be in the omitted `GROUP BY`. MySQL allows an omitted `GROUP BY`, but doesn't make that assumption, instead returning the `FIRST()` of each omitted field, and every other DBMS errors out. Your best bet is to always be explicit as possible in your SQL statements so you don't run into any of the weird assumptions made by the DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is lenient about GROUP BY clause.

But this practice is wrong, according to the ANSI SQL definition.
If you think about migrate to other DBMS like Oracle, PostgresQL... put GROUP BY clause and its columns.

Furthermore, it is easier to understand when tou put it.

Comment: Thanks Pastor.  If I understand you, it might not be absolutely needed with MySQL, but it should be used with other databases and to improve readability.

Comment: @user1032531, and newer MySQL versions require the GROUP BY clause. (Perhaps there's a backward compatibility mode?)